# The potential profile of two batteries in series

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity

[image]

I would like to know the potential profile in two batteries in series, like the battery in the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

For a two cells series, you have to continue by repeating the same profile and putting Cu (from the 1st cell) and Zn (from the 2nd cell) at the same potential level. The e.m.f. will be doubled.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. SO, my further question: for single cell, the half cell potentials of Cu2+/Cu is 0.337V vs SHE, and Zn2+/Zn is -0.718 vs. SHE. let's assume that the potential at the Cu lead is 0.337V and that of the Zn lead is -0.7618 V. Now with a second cell added, what is the potential of the Cu and Zn leads?